# ical file saves as Multiple times in outlook for the same Event and shows as conflict

Tags: outlook, icalendar

When I try to open the ics file multiple times and save it multiple times  in Mac Machines it will be saved as only one instance, but in windows outlook the same ics  if I open multiple times and save multiple times,  it  will save as  multiple instances

Here is my  ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20121205T160000Z
DTEND:20121205T164500Z
UID:1ED83D316-B120-441D-8D15-3A8B37275060
SUMMARY: Test Ics  for Multiple Instances 
DESCRIPTION: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, palpat venas tanquam vero quo.\n Interrogo nata dum animae tertio eam sed eu fides piissimi sibi ambulare est cum autem Apolloni sed. Etiam audiens.
LOCATION:My Own Location, Place
SEQUENCE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT00H15M00S
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

You can see the output :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqyG0.png

How can I  fix this  Issue.